# Posiible to use pandoc with HTML containing base64 inline images?

Tags: base64, pandoc

I want to convert an HTML file containing base64 encoded images to DOCX.
When I do this using pandoc the base64 images are not converted.

**Is it possible to include the base64 images using pandoc?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

See https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--self-contained

```
pandoc --self-contained --metadata pagetitle="title" index.md -o index-out.html
```

This feature was unavailable due to a [bug](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1062), but has been fixed since May, 2014.

Comment: It also works when going from Markdown to HTML. All references to images will be base64-encoded.

Answer (score 8):

With last version, use

```
pandoc --standalone --embed-resources --metadata pagetitle="title" index.md -o index-out.html
```