# How to convert a DOCX file with figures to a standalone HTML file using base64 using Pandoc?

Tags: html, image, base64, docx, pandoc

The following question (and there're a few more places where this issue has been discussed and resolved) discusses how to convert an `.html` file with `base64` images to a `.docx` file.
[Posiible to use pandoc with HTML containing base64 inline images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059542/posiible-to-use-pandoc-with-html-containing-base64-inline-images)

I want to go the other way — convert `.docx` which has images to a standalone `.html` file with `base64` code which reproduces (not necessarily with the same quality) the images present in the `.docx` file. For starters, I tried:

> pandoc -s -o chapter1.html cc.docx

as well as

> pandoc -o chapter1.html cc.docx

In both cases the `.html` file generated contains lines like `img src="media/image1.png"` which indicate that **Pandoc** tried to create (or thinks it has created) a folder named `media` where the figures from the `.docx` file are placed. But there is no such folder created by **Pandoc**. In any case I want the `.html` file to be a standalone document (just like the `.docx` file) and I don't need the folder.

I tried looking this up on the web, but the only solutions I get, pertain to the problem of converting `base64` images in `.html` to `.docx` and not the other way round.

Comment: Have you tried the `--self-contained` option?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it didn't work two years ago (March 2013) when you asked. Now it does, with the latest version of Pandoc (v1.13.2.1):

```
pandoc -o out.html --self-contained in.docx
```

Comment: improvment: --self-contained is nowadays deprecated `[WARNING] Deprecated: --self-contained. use --embed-resources --standalone`

btw: I used it for extrac images, e.g. see this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63220021/can-one-extract-images-from-pandocs-self-contained-html-files)  please. Good luck